# How to use a Backbone Model with Node.js and AMD (require.js on the browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, requirejs, js-amd

I currently have a working [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) Backbone Model using require.js like so:

```
// models/game.js
define(['backbone'],
function(Backbone) {

  var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot  : '/games/'
  , defaults : {
      name : null
    }
  });

  return Game;
});
```

The AMD/Backbone organization comes from [this tutorial](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) and [jrburke's Pull Request for Backbone](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/710).

I'd like to use the Backbone Model in Node.js too, because sharing Backbone models and collections has worked well in the past when not using AMD and, well, apparently I'm a masochist.

So I tried the following (inspired by the Backbone mod):

```
// models/game.js
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    factory(root, exports, require('backbone'));
  }
  else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['backbone'], function(Backbone, exports) {
      factory(root, exports, Backbone);
    });
  }
}(this, function(root, Game, Backbone) {

  Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot  : '/games/'
  , defaults : {
      name : null
    }
  });

  return Game;
}));
```

But `Game` is now undefined when I include it in the browser:

```
// collections/games.js
define(['backbone', 'models/game'],
function(Backbone, Game) {

  var Games = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Game

  , initialize: function() {
      console.log(Game) 
      // Game is undefined
      var game = new Game({ name: 'game1' });
    }
  });

  return Games;
});
```

While I looked at the [CommonJS notes](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html), I'm afraid I'm still unclear. **How do I use the same Backbone Model file as an AMD file in the browser and as a Node.js module?**

And for bonus: ***Is there a cleaner way than the ~10 lines at the top of each file?*** Ideally without the [define shim](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/blob/3b71989f4cfc2e8acef0307974ae3a490bd4aac6/examples/modular-backbone/js/libs/jquery/jquery.js).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried doing it AMD way on node as well?

http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html - might be best solution if you want to have the same AMD modules on both client and backend side.